# Support for multiple active overlapping surface views in Android

Tags: android, surfaceview, overlapping

I am currently working on an Android App that needs several overlapping SurfaceViews in one screen.

To be precise, I have two active overlapping SurfaceViews, one connected to Camera and the other connected to MediaPlayer. It mostly works but is not stable. At times, one of the SurfaceViews does not show up.

I saw a thread from 2009(http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/08e7df2e96a7973d) that says overlapping SurfaceViews are not supported in Android. Is this still the case? Anyone can share experience on this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found it out myself. Call setZOrderOnTop(true) on the SurfaceView I want to have on top seems solve the problem

Comment: It did it for me, too! Great, great, great, superb, perfect! :-D

Comment: Was just about to lose hope.. You are a hero

Comment: Where should I call this method? I have used this in onCreate() but it's still not working for me sometimes. It's weird behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

```
surface.setZOrderOnTop(true);
surface.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
```

If two of Surfaceview are set, there will be a problem of occlusion, if you want one of them to be at the top, then only set Setzorderontop (true), but in doing so, it will always be at the top, and any other view will be blocked, if you set Setzorderontop and set Setzordermediaoverlay, that Setzorderontop will fail

Answer (score 0):

I had written an application once, with overlapping Linear Layouts. It worked fine when I overlapped them with `view.layout(l,t,r,b)`. I am  not sure if that also works with SurfaceViews. How do you overlap them?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I think surfaceview is a bit different from other regular views. I use framelayout to overlap them.<>